# dispatch_async ( queue, block) vs dispatch_async (queue) { block }

Tags: swift2

Is there any difference between these two snippets? In the first one, the block is inside the `dispatch` part. Tks

```
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                //do something
            })

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                //do something
            }
```

Comment: Read *Trailing Closures* in [Swift Language Guide - Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no difference between these two blocks.

It is part of Swift's ability to accept closures provided as an argument after the function parentheses.

*NB: This answer and its examples are written in Swift 3, but the syntax for Swift 2 should be similar.*

Consider the following situation:

```
func a(callback: (_ s: String) -> Void) {
    callback(s: "hello there")
}
```

This function can be expressed as either, similar to your snippets:

```
a(callback: { str in
    print(str)    // prints "hello there"
})
```

or

```
a() { str in
    print(str)    // also prints "hello there"
}
```

Closures with similar behavior are seen in other functions/methods that require closures such as `autoreleasepool`, Dispatch and `URLConnection`. From a personal standpoint, I almost always use the first example as it is more readable.